# OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/usr/local/lib64/python3.6',

Tags: python-3.x, cpanel

I get this error when I try to install packages mentioned in my requirements.txt file of my project. I'm trying to host this project using `cPanel`. I am using `cPanel` terminal to do this.

I have tried running the command `pip3 install -r requirements.txt`